# How to draw a perfect triangle inside a circle orientated like a play button

Tags: java, android, canvas, shapes, geometry

I want to create a button which is a circle but has a triangle in the middle. 
For a send button. I tried using xml and drawable but there are always problems when it comes to screensize and views are not centered always etc..

So how can I do that using just a canvas?
Like how do I get the points I need to draw, say, given the radius of circle, and a scale of sorts, give me points for the triangle and draw the circle.
Here is a image of what I want

[image: this what I need]

Comment: why not use images available online? (unless you really want to code it from scratch, including the button)

Comment: Why not draw an SVG in Inkscape?

Comment: Here is code for creating a "perfect" n-gon: https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/PolygonFactory.java

Comment: Why don't you use vector icons instead? Your designer can achieve centered icon by moving icon to right side. I am just wondering.

Comment: agreed, why dont you use `VectorDrawable[Compat]`?

Comment: Did you mean "oriented"?

Answer (score 0):

I recently created something very similar to what you want..

Take a look at this: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2wpnxwwnty
To see how the math/scaling works.

This is the class which resulted:

```
public class TriangleInscribedCircle {

    private Triangle inscribedTriangle;

    private double s = 1;
    private double r = 100;

    public TriangleInscribedCircle(float radius, float scale) {
        setScale(scale);
        this.r = radius;
        calculateTriangle();
    }

    public Triangle getInscribedTriangle() {
        return this.inscribedTriangle;
    }

    public double getScale() {
        return this.s;
    }

    public void setScale(double scale) {
        if (scale < 0 || scale > 12) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Scale must be between 0 and 12.");
        }
        this.s = scale;
        calculateTriangle();
    }

    public double getCircleRadius() {
        return this.r;
    }

    public void setCircleRadius(double radius) {
        this.r = radius;
        calculateTriangle();
    }

    private void calculateTriangle() {
        double u = -((r) / (s + 1)) + r;
        double x = (6 * u + 10 * r - Math.sqrt(36 * Math.pow(r, 2) + 24 * r * u - 12 * Math.pow(u, 2))) / (8);
        double ax = x;
        double ay = -Math.tan(Math.toRadians(30)) * (x - 2 * r + u) + r;
        double bx = -u + 2 * r;
        double by = r;
        double cx = x;
        double cy = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(30)) * (x - 2 * r + u) + r;

        Point a = new Point(ax, ay);
        Point b = new Point(bx, by);
        Point c = new Point(cx, cy);

        if (this.inscribedTriangle == null) {
            this.inscribedTriangle = new Triangle(a, b, c);
        } else {
            this.inscribedTriangle.setA(a);
            this.inscribedTriangle.setB(b);
            this.inscribedTriangle.setC(c);
        }
    }

}
```

then inside your custom view

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    int radius = width / 2;

    canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius, mTextFieldEmpty ? mCircleDisabledPaint : mCirclePaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mTrianglePath, mTextFieldEmpty ? mTriangleDisabledPaint : mTrianglePaint);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mTriangle = new TriangleInscribedCircle(w / 2, 1);
    calculatePath();
}


private void calculatePath() {
    mTrianglePath.reset();
    mTrianglePath.moveTo((int) mTriangle.getInscribedTriangle().getA().x, (int) mTriangle.getInscribedTriangle().getA().y);
    mTrianglePath.lineTo((int) mTriangle.getInscribedTriangle().getB().x, (int) mTriangle.getInscribedTriangle().getB().y);
    mTrianglePath.lineTo((int) mTriangle.getInscribedTriangle().getC().x, (int) mTriangle.getInscribedTriangle().getC().y);
    mTrianglePath.lineTo((int) mTriangle.getInscribedTriangle().getA().x, (int) mTriangle.getInscribedTriangle().getA().y);
}
```

Comment: what is Triangle in the TangleInscribedCircle class? it shows red

Comment: Its just a holder class for 3 Points, A,B,C. Point is a holder of an X and a Y.